# Lubuntu 18.04 VM - can't edit network connections after changing IP address

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, clone

I cloned a Lubuntu 18.04 VM (running on ESXi). When I started the cloned copy I edited the network connections (using the menu in the lower right corner of the screen) and changed the IPV4 IP address so as not to clash with the original VM, then rebooted.
Now I am unable to edit the network connections - nothing happens when I select "Edit Connection" from the networking menu in the lower right corner. I've also noticed that the IP address that I specified isn't being used - it seems to be getting a DHCP-assigned IP address.
Any idea how I can get back in to fix this?

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: Yes I was. I was hoping that just once I might get an answer to my question rather than the standard "why don't you upgrade to a newer version" response :0(   (I don't use Linux much and don't have time for the upgrades and associated upheaval)

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else who encounters the same issue: I found the solution in another forum. This is what I needed to do to set a static IP address of 192.168.1.37 (my gateway is 192.168.1.1):

1.Find the id of the relevant network adapter (using ifconfig) - e.g. mine was "ens160"
2.Edit /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml as follows

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
ens160:
dhcp4: no
addresses: [192.168.1.37/24]
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
nameservers:
addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```